# Nexus 7's MTP does not connect in mass storage mode anymore

Tags: nexus-7, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I've had a Nexus 7 for a year now and since the day I've got it, I could easily connect it to my PC and transfer file to/from it in MTP mode. But some weeks ago I tried installing Ubuntu on it and since I failed, I downloaded and reinstalled Android on it. But ever since, it is not recognized as a mass storage on my PC!

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've occasionally seen a new (or factory reset) N7 refuse to appear on a PC until you change the storage mode to camera then back to MTP. From memory (I don't have my N7 to hand) go to Settings, Storage, tap the three dot menu and there is an option to change the storage mode there.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work! Switching to PTP opens the tablet's picture folder on my PC but switching back to MTP does nothing (other than closing the picture folder). Any other idea?

Comment: It's starnge that PTP works but MTP doesn't. I'd probably resort to flashing a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) using fastboot, unless of course that's what you did to remove Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely a hardware issue. I recommend you get your device repaired by sending it to [Google/Asus](https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/3070579?hl=en#ts=3070585,3070683).

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling drivers.

There is a tool in the Nexus root toolkit

http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/